# FortiClient SSLVPN Configuration

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to setup VPN connection using mentioned software on `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`. Binary source: [SOURCE](https://kb.arubacloud.pl/files/tar-gz/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4-0-2281-tar.aspx). The application is 32 bit while operating system is 64 bit, after installing some libraries app run. I have found that app doesn't recognize domain names, so I use numbers. After clicking `Connect`, I receive `Notice`:

```
Insufficient credential(s). Please check the password, client certificate, etc.
```

`Status` in `Connection status` window is:

```
Set up tunnel failed
```

Below I am attaching "mock" configuration screen. One maybe **important** thing is, that I have to use `Remote Gateway`: `https://127.0.0.1:777/sth` not `127.0.0.1:777`, but how to configure something like this? When I insert `127.0.0.1/sth` in `Server:` I receive:

```
Start SSLVPN error: Can not resolve FortiGate address
```

Credentials are correct, there is not certificate which I should provide. Maybe should I first unistall `FortiClient 6.0 for Linux` which I had installed before `FortiClient SSLVPN` installation? Maybe should I force software to recognize domain name? Before I try to connect, during app start I receive some logs, should I worry about them?

```
Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
...
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to loction theme engine in module_path:"murrine" 
...
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Maybe should I open `777` tunnel? But, I believe, I have already done that. Could you help me overcome this?

[image: forti_client_mock_configuration]

**EDIT:**

Below I am listing actions I have made which did not help:

- Uninstalling `FortiClient 6.0 for Linux`
- Adding line to `/etc/hosts` to let machine recognize domain name (here is mock):

  ```
   127.0.0.1    domain.name.com
  ```
- Solving (by software installation) issues with `atk-bridge`, `murrine`, `canberra-gtk-module`

I would like to add, that when I visit `https://127.0.0.1:777/sth` via browser, I see login box and I am able to log in (it proves that credentials (login and password) are correct). Maybe the problem lies in the certificate: the browser is able to somehow overcome that, while the `FortiClient SSLVPN` application is not? But as far as I know there is not certificate. Do you happen to know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the IP address in trusted sites using 'internet options', this worked for me.